# How to set replace command if target will dynamic href is comming

Tags: java, android

This is my Html:

```
desc=desc=<a target="_blank" href="http://www.taxmann.com/corporatelaws/fileopencontainer.aspx?Page=CIRNO&amp;id=27000000000000002519&amp;search=">A. P. (DIR Series) Circular No. 46 dated June 14, 2005</a>
```

here id= values changes and  corporatelaws or directtaxlaws

```
String   k = replace ( desc, "<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"http://www.taxmann.com/corporatelaws/fileopencontainer.aspx?Page=RULES&amp;id=35000000000000001648&amp;search=\">", "");
```

In desc I'm getting HTML I have replace command I have to remove link so I'm pick data from anchor tag target is dynamic where id varies I'm able to replace linking to text whose target is

http://www.taxmann.com/corporatelaws/fileopencontainer.aspx?Page=RULES&id=35000000000000001648&search=\

but when ever target changes, I mean to say if id changes, it doesn't replace link as text.

Please tell me how to get and set the id values so that if target will be dynamic we can replace link as text. I'm new to android programming.

```
String str = "http://www.taxmann.com/corporatelaws/fileopencontainer.aspx?Page=CIRNO&amp;id=27000000000000002519&amp;search=";
int indexoff = str.indexOf("id=");
int indexofl = str.indexOf("&amp;search=");

String strsub = str.substring(indexoff + 3, indexofl - indexoff - 3);
String strstaticstring = "http://www.taxmann.com/corporatelaws/fileopencontainer.aspx?Page=CIRNO&amp;id=" + strsub + "&amp;search=";
String k = desc.replace(strstaticstring, "");
```

i have trying this one bUt i dont know how to pick corporte or directtaxlaws will come ..

Comment: how these two words are changing?

Comment: "http://www.taxmann.com/corporatelaws/fileopencontainer.aspx?Page=CIRNO&amp;id=27000000000000002519&amp;search=";
in this corporate changes it come some time direct taxlaws and id values id=...value there two changes in target href

Answer (score 0):

try this way:

```
String str ="";
if(desc.contains("http://www.taxmann.com/corporatelaws/")==true)
{
 str = "http://www.taxmann.com/corporatelaws/fileopencontainer.aspx?Page=CIRNO&amp;id=27000000000000002519&amp;search=";
}

if(desc.contains("http://www.taxmann.com/directtaxlaws/")==true)
{
 str = "http://www.taxmann.com/directtaxlaws/fileopencontainer.aspx?Page=CIRNO&amp;id=27000000000000002519&amp;search=";
}

if(desc.contains("http://www.taxmann.com/corporte/")==true)
{
 str = "http://www.taxmann.com/corporte/fileopencontainer.aspx?Page=CIRNO&amp;id=27000000000000002519&amp;search=";
}
```

or you can split your string on the bases of "/" and check it for words corporte,directtaxlaws etc.

```
String str = "http://www.taxmann.com/corporatelaws/fileopencontainer.aspx?Page=CIRNO&amp;id=27000000000000002519&amp;search=";      
 string[] strarr = str.Split('/');
```

in strarr[3] u will get corporatelaws value sa string use it for contracting whole string for replacing in desc

Comment: String strsub = str.substring(indexoff + 3, indexofl - indexoff -3);java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException    out of bousnt exceptionis oming

Comment: check if(indexoff !=-1 && indexofl !=-1 ){String strsub = str.substring(indexoff + 3, indexofl - indexoff -3);}

Comment: i have put that also still same Exception

Comment: @DevenKumar : where u updated your code i'm not able to find it can u give me a link?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10027287/how-to-set-replace-command-if-target-will-dynamic-href-is-comming/10027500#comment12826253_10027500